# Common idiom to avoid IE throw: Error: 'console' is undefined

Tags: javascript, console, firebug, undefined

I've installed firebug and I wrote all these log statements.

I've tested my app  in IE and of course I've got "undefined" error.

What's the common idiom to avoid this.

I don't really feel like commenting all the console.log statements in my file nor to mock them.

Well I'm not sure what to do.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

i usually make a wrapper function like so:

```
function log(obj) {
    if (window.console && console.log) console.log(obj);
}
```

or you could do something like this at the beginning of your script file/element:

```
if (!window.console) { 
    window.console = {
        log: function(obj){ /* define own logging function here, or leave empty */ }
    };
}
```

Comment: And comment/uncomment that single line when debugging?

Comment: Ahh no, it will return false on firefox+firebug :)

Answer (score 1):

Paul Irish has a better wrapper for `console.log()`.

http://paulirish.com/2009/log-a-lightweight-wrapper-for-consolelog/

This allows multiple arguments, and provides a history (for debugging) in case no console is there or (eg Firebug Lite) the console is created later.