# Twitter script not working in IE9?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, api, twitter

I'm trying to get this script to work in IE9, but not sure whats wrong...it should just pull the feed of my twitter...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.getJSON("http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=somiac&callback=?",
          function(data) {
            for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
                if(i==3) 
                    break;
                console.log(data[i].text);
                $('.tweet_container').append("<div class='tweet'>" + data[i].text + "</div>");  
            }
          });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: This script works peoperly for me. Why do you think there's smth wrong at all?

Answer (score 0):

as far as i know there is no console.log() integrated with internet explorer ...

Comment: i mean your script will throw an exception in ie (unless of course you defined some fallback for console.log)

Comment: If the F12 Developer Tools is not open, (window.)console (and thus (window.)console.log is undefined. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1146309/common-idiom-to-avoid-ie-throw-error-console-is-undefined  Yaaay Explorer!