# Internet Explorer and console.log

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, javascript, unobtrusive-javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Common idiom to avoid IE throw: Error: 'console' is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1146309/common-idiom-to-avoid-ie-throw-error-console-is-undefined)
>   ['console' is undefined error for internet explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3326650/console-is-undefined-error-for-internet-explorer)

Is there a reliable way I can guard against "console.log" causing a bug in IE?

While I find console.log extremely useful, it is always a source of grief with Internet Explorer.

If it's just statements that I have left in my code, that's fine, I could deal with that. But sometimes I find that there are "console.log" calls in JavaScript libraries I am using - which cause IE to crash or, on IE8/9, will only work while the Dev tools console window (F12) is open.

What I am looking for is either:

- a library that emulates console.log on IE6/7/8/9 so it doesn't crash everything when something tries console.log()
- a way to guard against this error.

Comment: What libraries do you use that leave `console.log` calls in production code? You shouldn't be doing that either, which would solve the problem!

Comment: Just use `window.console && window.console.log('test')` everytime and there won't be any problem.

Comment: Best thing is to file bug reports with those libraries to remove them. They should not be in production code.