# IE alternative to console.log()

Tags: javascript

So after looking around a bit, I've found console.log() can blow up IE9.
So I can't leave any in my code, that being the case, what could I do here?

I have my data_box which displays some text the user has inputted. But, if there is no text, I want to call showMsg(), which creates a new box with some text, 'No Text Here'.

```
(data_box.length) ? console.log('') : showMsg();
```

What alternative can I replace 'console.log('')' with to tell that ternary function to do nothing if data_box exists?

Comment: why not `if(data_box.length) { showMsg()}` ?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, it seems like an `if` statement would do the trick. `if(data_box.length > 0){ showMsg(); }`.

Comment: You can just mock out console.log to avoid the error instead. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1146309/common-idiom-to-avoid-ie-throw-error-console-is-undefined

Comment: I want showMsg() to be called if data_box doesn't exsist. So wouldn't if(data_box.length) { showMsg()} be incorrect?

Comment: possible duplicate of ['console' is undefined error for Internet Explorer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3326650/console-is-undefined-error-for-internet-explorer)

Comment: @Daft well, sorry just negate the condition: `if(!data_box.length){ showMsg()}`

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry. I was just wondering if I had made a mistake in my original code. Cheers chumkiu!

Comment: @chumkiu if you wanna throw you answer down below, i'll select it as right.

Comment: This is a moot question.  You are using `console.log` for a useless purpose here anyway.  Don't use a ternary operator if you don't need an else statement, use a simple if statement.

Comment: Thank's for the incredibly helpful response Ennui. I'm just lucky not everyone here is as unbelievably helpful as you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There’s no logical reason to use `console.log` for this purpose.

Simply you can avoid the ternary operation if you don’t need an `else` (in some case is more short than ternary operator).

```
if(!data_box.length){ showMsg()}
```

If you want absolutely the ternary operator you can do this:

```
data_box.length? null : showMsg();
```

Or if you want absolutely a function (I don’t see any valid reason… however it’s just an exercise), you can declare a function `doNothing` in this way:

```
function doNothing() {}
```

and

```
(data_box.length)? doNothing() : showMsg();
```

or without function delcaration:

```
data_box.length? (function() {})() : showMsg();
```

or again:

```
data_box.length || showMsg();
```

and so on… :-)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest thing to do is to write your own `console.log` function and use it if the browser doesn't provide one.

```
window.console = window.console || { log: function () { } };
```

… but it would be a better idea to strip your debugging routines from your code before it goes to production.

Comment: Well I'm not really using it for debugging purposes, it's more used here to just 'do nothing' if the ternary operator returns true.

Comment: I'd just use a regular `if` statement for that. Much cleaner and more self-documenting.

Answer (score 0):

I'd have given you few lines of code to make it work, but following blog has done great job in addressing the issue. Do read this

```
http://patik.com/blog/complete-cross-browser-console-log/
```

Answer (score 0):

As for myself, i've stopped using directly `console.log()`. It is too much character !

I have my own `log()` function :

```
function log() {
    var arg = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);

    if (console && console.log) {
        console.log.apply(console, arg);
    } else {
        for (var i = 0; i < arg.length; i++) alert(arg[i]);
    }
}
```

Then you can call it :

```
log('test', {}, ['test', 'hello']);
```

In ie, it will pop 3 alert : `'test', [object Object], 'test,hello'`

---

## Edit

To *"do nothing if true"*, you can do that :

```
(data_box.length) || showMsg();
```

But really, it is better to use an `if`:

```
if(!data_box.length) showMsg();
```